# AWSFacebookLogin is using deprecated UIWebView in iOS

Tags: swift

In my project AWS is being used. It uses pod 'AWSFacebookSignIn'. Now as the UIWebView is deprecated by Apple the app will be rejected on Appstore. 
AWS is using FBSDKCorekit and Bolts as I found through terminal.
Do I need to remove this 'AWSFacebookSignIn' from project or there is an upgrade available for 'AWSFacebookSignIn' that resolves the deprecated UIWebView issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll note that you can still update your app for the next two weeks.

> The App Store will no longer accept new apps using UIWebView as of
>   April 2020 and app updates using UIWebView as of December 2020. [- Apple Developer News](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12232019b)

Try running the command `pod update` in your XCode project (by cd'ing into the directory of your project in the terminal). Then check for UIWebView usage.

However, I cannot help much more than this without seeing your Podfile. If you are installing the entire Amplify pod or AWSCore, then I would recommend just installing the portions you need, and perhaps that would fix the issue. Can you please attach / paste the Podfile?

It does appear that the pod 'AWSFacebookSignIn' does not use UIWebView, by scanning the .m files. [Source](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/tree/master/AWSAuthSDK/Sources/AWSFacebookSignIn) Therefore, it seems like you can keep the 'AWSFacebookSignIn' pod. Try running `pod update` and if that does not work, return here and paste your Podfile.

Comment: pod update is working fine for me. All the AWS pods are updated and there is no uiwebview used shown in there. But Crashlytics and Fabrics still using it.

Comment: @swiftDev Ah, in that case you can either (1) stop using them, (2) edit their source code and remove the webviews / change them for WKWebViews, or (3) wait until the developers update them (and ask them to do so!)

Comment: No. Actually fabrics and crashlytics also need to upgrade to a higher version.